# how to get total number of lines in csv file and append as new column based on line number by using nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv

I'd like to ask.

How to get the total number of rows in the CSV file using nodejs.

After that, I'd like to append a new column based on line number (into the same file or creating another file) by using nodejs.

Eg of CSV file

```
Justin,36 years
Jason, 37 years
```

Now it's 2 line, So i'd like to get

```
1,Justin,36 years
2,Jason, 37 years
```

in the same CSV file or creating another CSV file.

Please suggest to me how could I.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide the current way you read and rewrite the csv file.

Comment: thanks.current way is I read json object and write csv file. Not directly read csv file to write csv file.

Comment: Show me a `json object` example, update it to your question, pls!

Answer (score 0):

This should be relatively straightforward, I'll use the [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) module, though you could use any parser really.

We'll map each line, prepending the line number to each one, join and write to the output file.

```
const { promisify } = require("util");
const fs = require("fs");
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const parse = promisify(require("csv-parse"));

async function prependLineNumbers(inputFile, outputFile, delimiter = ",", eol = "\n") {
    const input = await readFile(inputFile, { encoding: "utf8" });
    const lines = await parse(input, { delimiter });
    // Prepend line number to each line...
    const output = lines.map((line, lineIndex) => [lineIndex + 1, ...line].join(delimiter)).join(eol)
    writeFile(outputFile, output);
}

prependLineNumbers("example.csv", "example_with_line_numbers.csv");
```